# How to change plot size in R?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to create two plots side-by-side, but the problem I am running into is that R seemingly can not enlarge the "plotting space", which results in shrinkage of both graphs on the x-axis like so:
[image]

You can also see that the line names also get cropped due to not enough space being present. Sow the question is: how do I make the plots wider and the labels fully visible? It would be great to avoid any libraries like `ggplot`, but if there is no other way, this will be fine as well.

Here is how the plots above are constructed:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2), 1, 2, byrow = TRUE))  
plot(plot1)
plot(plot2) # axis(4, at = coef1[nrow(coef1), ], labels = colnames(coef1), cex = 0.8, adj = 0, las=2)
```

Comment: `Error in plot(plot1) : object 'plot1' not found`. Can you post a reproducible example of plots 1 and 2?

Comment: Sorry, I can give an example, but the second plot actually uses the modified source code of the library, so it would simply be too big to comprehend. I think it is more appropriate to only give the functional bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a graphics device, such as `x11()`, `windows()` or `cairo()` setting the width and height. This will automatically resize the plot regions. In the example that follows, making them larger.

```
x11(width = 20, height = 4)
layout(matrix(c(1,2), 1, 2, byrow = TRUE))  
plot(1:10)
plot(-(1:10))
```

As for the margins, see `help("par")`, entries for `oma` and `mar`.

Comment: x11 is the only option that seems to work, but it still gives an error ```“unable to open connection to X11 display ''”```. I think this has to be because I am using google's collab as a notebook. Maybe there is something else I should do in this case?

Comment: These are the links for python. Unfortunately, I have to stick to the abomination of a language, which is R

Answer (score 0):

If you are working inside a Jupiter notebook, I found the answer on this link: https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/09/resizing-plots-in-the-r-kernel-for-jupyter-notebooks.html

```
library(repr)
library(ISLR)

options(repr.plot.width=20, repr.plot.height=20)
pairs(Auto)
```